# Does an Azure Function CosmosDb Change feed trigger dispose input documents if they are of type JsonDocument?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, system.text.json

I have the folllowing Azure Function with a CosmosDb change feed trigger:

```
        [Function("Example")]
        public async Task Run([CosmosDBTrigger(
                databaseName: "%DATABASE_NAME%",
                containerName: "example-container",
                Connection = "EXAMPLE_DATABASE_CONNECTION",
                LeaseContainerName = "example-container-leases",
                LeaseContainerPrefix = "Example",
                CreateLeaseContainerIfNotExists = true)]
            IReadOnlyList<JsonDocument> documents)
       {
         // do stuff with the documents
       }
```

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/use-dom#jsondocument-is-idisposable) states that `JsonDocument builds an in-memory view of the data into a pooled buffer. Therefore the JsonDocument type implements IDisposable and needs to be used inside a using block.` Does Azure Functions handle this itself or should I dispose them manually? Could it cause issues in the function if they are not disposed at all?

Comment: Can you change the signature of the method?  Does it have to be `JsonDocument`?  Could you use `JsonElement` or `JsonNode`?

Comment: `JsonDocument` is immutable and faster according to the documentation which fits the use case but otherwise I could.

Answer (score 0):

> Does Azure Functions handle dispose JsonDocument itself

I didn't get any MS documentation which says that Azure function handles it but you can use my below code to dispose it manually.

**`Code:`**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.Json;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionApp7
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public Function1(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Function1>();
        }

        [Function("Function1")]
        public void Run([CosmosDBTrigger(
            databaseName: "example-database",
            collectionName: "example-container",
            ConnectionStringSetting = "EXAMPLE_DATABASE_CONNECTION",
            LeaseCollectionName = "example-container-leases",
            LeaseCollectionPrefix ="Example",
            CreateLeaseCollectionIfNotExists =true)] IReadOnlyList<JsonDocument> documents)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("C# CosmosDB change feed trigger function processed a batch of {0} documents", documents.Count);
            foreach (var document in documents)
            {
                try
                {

                    string jsonString = document.RootElement.GetRawText();
                    MyModel model = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyModel>(jsonString);

                    Console.WriteLine($"Model Data: {jsonString}");

                }
                finally
                {
                    document.Dispose();

                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class MyModel
    {
        public string? Property1 { get; set; }
        public string? Property2 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**`Output:`**

[image]

> Could it cause issues in the function if they are not disposed at all

As there is no specific documentation which states azure function handles the IDisposable itself, so its always a best practice to garbage collect. You can refer this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48945526/do-we-have-to-take-care-of-garbage-collection-in-azure-function) too which says the same.